# Convert Matrix to column major order format

Tags: r, matrix, column-major-order

I was using `Rsymphony` and decided that I would like to use `CPLEX`.  I am working through the `cplexAPI` in R and would rather use my existing structure for building a constraint matrix.  The documentation says that the API takes the constraint matrix in column major order format with only the non-zero elements.  So I need a way to (elegantly, I hope) convert a matrix into this form.

For example:

> 3.2 Creating and solving a mixed integer programming (MIP) problem
>   In the following, an example MIP will be created and solved:
>   ...

subject to:

[image: constraints]

Currently, this is implemented as a matrix

```
> mat = matrix(c(-1, 1, 1, 10, 
+                 1, -3, 1, 0, 
+                 0, 1, 0, -3.5),byrow = TRUE, nrow=3,ncol=4)
> mat
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   -1    1    1 10.0
[2,]    1   -3    1  0.0
[3,]    0    1    0 -3.5
```

From the documentation, I need the following elements.

> The constraint matrix is passed in column major order format. Be careful here: all indices start with 0! Begin indices of rows.

```
beg <- c(0, 2, 5, 7)
```

You will note that working from the top left down is how this works.  In the first position (0) the second column begins with the third non-zero element, the third with the fifth, etc.

> Number of non-zero elements per row.

```
cnt <- c(2, 3, 2, 2)
```

Again, what I would have said was columns.

> Column indices.

```
ind <- c(0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 2)
```

This is the column index of each non-zero element.

> Non-zero elements.

```
val <- c(-1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -3.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 10.0, -3.5)
```

I am stumped on finding a way to get this done.

I know I can create `val` easily by:

```
c(mat)
[1] -1.0  1.0  0.0  1.0 -3.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0 10.0  0.0 -3.5
val2 <- mat[mat !=0]
val <- c(-1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -3.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 10.0, -3.5)
val2 & val
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

I can create `cnt` easily by:

```
cnt <- apply(mat,2,function(x) Matrix::nnzero(x, na.counted = NA))
cnt
[1] 2 3 2 2
```

Thanks to @42-

```
ind2 <- row(mat)[which(mat != 0)]-1
ind <- c(0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 2)
ind2 == ind
[1] TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

## Now for `beg`.

Restating the pieces,

```
mat
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   -1    1    1 10.0
[2,]    1   -3    1  0.0
[3,]    0    1    0 -3.5
beg <- c(0, 2, 5, 7)
val <- c(-1.0, 1.0, 1.0, -3.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 10.0, -3.5)
```

`beg` is an index that counts along the position of the non-zero element in `val`.  So in `mat[1,1]` is the first non-zero element in `mat` and the first (0) element in `val`. In `mat[,2]` the first non-zero elment is the third element (2) in `val`.  In `mat[,3]` the first non-zero element is the sixth (5) element in `val` and in `mat[,4]` the first non-zero element is the eighth (7) element of `val`.

Clear as mud?  Me too.

Answer (score 2):

It's not exactly clear to me what you are hoping for but here is a method to generate the row and column numbers that would index the non-zero entries in that matrix using zero-based indexing (which is not normal for R-matrix indexing although as you have seen that rule does not apply to sparse matrices constructed with Matrix-package functions.):

```
row(mat)[which(mat != 0)]-1
#[1] 0 1 0 1 2 0 1 0 2
col(mat)[which(mat != 0)]-1
#[1] 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 3 3
```

Comment: Thank you!  This will certainly work for `ind`.  I agree that it is not clear, I am trying to work with an API that took me a while to wrap my head around.

Comment: I briefly saw a checkmark. Was there something else that was needed? Do you need a different row definition?

Comment: Yes one more piece, I added some explanation.  I need the `beg`.  I didnt know if I could give the checkmark for part of the answer or what.